# Move an implementation from one file to another keeping git tracking

Tags: java, git

Here is my problem.

Inside a same repository I have multiple projects.
Lets call them `A` and `B` (and forget about `C`, `D`, and all the others who are irrelevant in the current subject).

In `A` I have a class (let's call it `SuperUsefull`) with some logic that is pretty usefull all across my system but project `A` is not made to be available to my other projects.
`B`'s classes on the other hand are available to all projects.

So what I would like to do is to move `SuperUsefull` from `A` to `B` but I would like to keep git history tracking in git (like blame and such).
BUT, `A` is a very big project which I can not fully refactor at current time.
So I thought I could proceed as follows :

```java
package org.company.a;
/**
 * a comment explaining why this class has been deprecated and where to find the new one.
 */
@Deprecated
public class SuperUsefull extends org.company.b.SuperUsefull {}
```

So my problem is how to (in the same commit) have
 - the displacement of logic
 - keep tracking on the code even if it goes in another file
 - have a file considered new where the was one in the previous commit
 - keep all this in a way that the world sees it as one commit as it only make sense when all the event happen at the same time.

Is it possible ?
Do I have to git move then create the file and add it ? Is it legit ?
Do I have to make to commit and squash them before pushing ? What is the best practice here ?